# What are the state variables like temperature after the system has done an adiabatic irreversible process?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, adiabatic, reversibility

Consider a system containing ideal gas which is initially at a volume $V_{1}$ and then suddenly its volume is increased to a volume $V_{2}$. What is the final temperature of the system if the initial temperature is $T_{1}$? Will the temperature be different from that of the irreversible process if the same work is done through reversible process?

Comment: Hi Muthi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Adiabatic process would mean no heat transfer between the surrounding and the system.
Irreversiblility would mean entropy definitely changed after the process.

Let's say, entropy increased (which is obviously natural) after the process.
The increase in entropy of the system is because its volume is suddenly increased (and so did the disorder and unpredictability of the molecules after the process).

If entropy is kept constant {isentropic process = (reversible + adiabatic) process}, all the volume expansion will be converted to work, and T temperature would remain constant. But if the process is irreversible (i.e. entropy changes), then so would Temperature.

So, although adiabatic means no heat transfer from/into the system. i.e. intuitively it seems that no temperature change in the system. But entropy also goes along temperature and should entropy changes (irreversible process) so would the temperature. Entropy is the quality (microscopic) of hotness/coolness and temperature (in its conventional form) is the degree/quantity of hotness/coolness (macroscopic).